# Adding header to response for specific URLs with HAproxy

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy

I have a simple condition in my HAproxy config (I tried this for *frontend* and *backend*):

```
acl no_index_url path_end .pdf .doc .xls .docx .xlsx
rspadd X-Robots-Tag:\ noindex if no_index_url
```

It should add the no-robots header to content that should not be indexed. However it gives me this `WARNING` when parsing the config:

```
acl 'no_index_url' will never match because it only involves keywords
    that are incompatible with 'backend http-response header rule'
```

and

```
acl 'no_index_url' will never match because it only involves keywords
    that are incompatible with 'frontend http-response header rule'
```

According to [documentation](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#4-rspadd), `rspadd` can be used in both *frontend* and *backend*. The `path_end` is used in examples within *frontend*. Why am I getting this error and what does it mean?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Starting in HaProxy 1.6 you won't be able to just ignore the error message. To get this working use the temporary variable feature:

```
frontend main
   http-request set-var(txn.path) path

backend local
   http-response set-header X-Robots-Tag noindex if { var(txn.path) -m end .pdf .doc }
```

Comment: You saved my day :)

Comment: This might be useful as a solution, although it is not useful (I think) in my situation, where I use HAProxy via OpnSense. Any feedback on the actual question of `Why am I getting this error and what does it mean`?

Comment: OK. I found the answer here: https://discourse.haproxy.org/t/http-response-set-header-with-condition-not-working/3108/2 . Not sure why this works like that, by anyway...

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, even with the warning, having the `acl` within the frontend works perfectly fine. All the resources with .pdf, .doc, etc are getting the correct `X-Robots-Tag` added to them.

In other words, this `WARNING` is misleading and in reality the `acl` **does** match.

Comment: Just a note for anyone coming across this, in 1.6.2 it does add the header despite the warning but also adds it to any response not matching the rule so I believe it is actually being ignored. That was the case for me anyway,  I was using an 'unless' if that makes a difference.  The accepted answer worked for me so try that.

Answer (score 0):

if using haproxy below v1.6, create a new backend block (could be a duplicate of the default backend) and add the special headers in there. then in frontend use that backend conditionally. i.e.

```
use_backend alt_backend if { some_condition }
```

admittedly not an ideal solution but it does the job.